# COM object not working after migrating to IIS 7.5

Tags: dll, com, vbscript, wix

I am moving a classic ASP application from IIS6 to IIS7.5 and I am having troubles with COM dependencies.

This is the problematic code

```
SET o = Server.CreateObject("ClassName")
Response.Write "Returned object: " & TypeName(o) 
result = o.SomeMethod()
```

The first line succeeds, the second line prints "Returned object: ClassName".

The third line ends with an error

- Error: 429
- Source: Provider
- Description: Class not registered

I don't know, whether that is a 32 x 64 bit issue (the server is 64bit, the old one was 32bit). But I did set the "Enable 32-Bit Application" property of the application pool to True.

Is it normal that Server.CreateObject returns an object and it is the method call that actually fails?

We are using WIX script to register the COM classes (I did not do any modifications in this part). 
I can find my class in the registry in Computer\HKEY_CLASSSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node.

I would appreciate any pointers, this drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got an instance of ClassName. No error on object creation and TypeName confirms it. So, the component is correctly registered.

But, does it reference another component which is used from the method you are calling? It seems a not controlled error raises from inside your class.

Comment: The same code works on the old server, so I don't think there is a bug in the code. If I understand you correctly, you say that there may be Server.CreateObject(xxx) call somewhere inside SomeMethod and it is the lookup for xxx which actually fails?

Comment: Not exactly. And no, no bug, just a unhandled error. If, for example, your component internally instantiate a Jet Database Connection, and in your new server the Jet Components are not available, your component can't create the connection. If this is not handled, the error bubbles up.